# Check if QSqlQuery::addBindValue() has failed

Tags: c++, qt, qsqlquery

How can I check if `QSqlQuery::addBindValue()` has failed? For example, there might not be any more placeholders left to be bound. Consider this code:

```
QSqlQuery q;
q.prepare("INSERT INTO table1 (field1) VALUES (?)");
q.addBindValue("value1");
q.addBindValue("value2"); // this one should fail
```

However, `addBindValue()` is a `void`, so it doesn't return information about whether it succeeded or failed.

Comment: Check q.exec(). If method return false, check error string. If you was wrong in binding, this error was described in error string.

Comment: exec() will not tell me which addBindValue() failed, so it doesn't work for me. I need to know which addBindValue() in particular failed.

Comment: `const int count = queryString.count('?');`

Comment: @sashoalm, IMO, you cannot analyze query and detect errors in it unless it is executed on the database.

Answer (score 0):

I finally stepped into the sources, and it seems you really can't find out if it has failed. It doesn't set the last error or any other error code:

```
void QSqlResult::bindValue(int index, const QVariant& val, QSql::ParamType paramType)
{
    Q_D(QSqlResult);
    d->binds = PositionalBinding;
    QList<int>& indexes = d->indexes[d->fieldSerial(index)];
    if (!indexes.contains(index))
        indexes.append(index);
    if (d->values.count() <= index)
        d->values.resize(index + 1);
    d->values[index] = val;
    if (paramType != QSql::In || !d->types.isEmpty())
        d->types[index] = paramType;
}
```